# HTML5 GeoLocation issue

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-emulator, geolocation

I am trying to use HMTL5 GeoLocation in Android emulator. Riht now I am trying a basic code to make it work on Android emulator. Here is that code

```
if(!navigator.geolocation) {
            alert("Your browser does not supporty geolocation");
        } else {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        }

        function success(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            alert(lat + ", " + lng);
        }

        function error(error) {
            alert("Error occurred " + error);
        }
```

Now when I run this code on Chrome on PC then it works fine. But when I run this code on Android Emulator then it shows this error

```
Error Occurred [objectPositionError]
```

How can I make it work on Android emulator?

Comment: Did you configured your emulator with GPS support? I believe it won't work without it.

Comment: No I did not. How can I configure it with GPS Support? I do not have real device thats why I am completely relying on emulator.

Comment: I followed this link http://www.mobilehtml5.com/post/1276879531/android-2-2-browser-geolocation-gotcha. but it still doesnt work. It now does not show any error but also it does not show mt lar and lng.

Comment: It doesnot even work on android device. I checked it on my friend's phone. :(

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome 50, mobile or desktop, they have stopped allowing geolocation to non-secure websites.  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en